# Error al crear un nuevo repositorio en Genexus-GAM

Tags: genexus

Cree una base de datos GAM usando la herramienta de implementación GAMDeployTool.
Cuando me conecto al repositorio GAM-Manager y quiero crear un nuevo repositorio después de llenar los datos requeridos me muestra el siguiente error: "Administrator User password is required. (GAM330)"
La única forma de que pude crear un repositorio fue copiando el repositorio GAM-Manager.
¿Alguien sabe por qué?